# Creating a min, basic and basic WL factur-x using mustang

Tags: java

I try to create a factur-x using mustang library.
I found how to create an EN16931 factur-x xml and how to embed it in the pdf.

For this I used the following code sample:

```
ZUGFeRDExporterFromA1 ze = new ZUGFeRDExporterFromA1().setProducer("My Application")
          .setCreator(System.getProperty("user.name")).setZUGFeRDVersion(2).ignorePDFAErrors()
          .load("blanko.pdf");
Invoice i = new Invoice()
          .setIssueDate(new Date())
          .setDueDate(new Date())
          .setDetailedDeliveryPeriod(new Date(), new Date())
          .setDeliveryDate(new Date())
          .setSender(
                  new TradeParty("ME", "teststr", "55232", "teststadt", "DE")
                          .addTaxID("4711")
                          .addVATID("DE0815")
                          .addBankDetails(new BankDetails("DE88200800000970375700", "COBADEFFXXX")))
          .setRecipient(
                  new TradeParty("Franz Müller", "teststr.12", "55232", "Entenhausen", "DE")
                          .addVATID("DE0815"))
          .setNumber("NUMFACTURE")
          .addItem(new Item(new Product("Testprodukt", "", "C62", new BigDecimal(19)), new BigDecimal(123), new BigDecimal(1)))
          .addItem(new Item(new Product("Testprodukt", "", "C62", new BigDecimal(19)), new BigDecimal(123), new BigDecimal(1)))
          .addItem(new Item(new Product("Testprodukt", "", "C62", new BigDecimal(19)), new BigDecimal(123), new BigDecimal(1)))
          .setCreditNote();
      ze.setTransaction(i);
      ze.export("factur-x-en16931.pdf");
```

This code work fine. I do generate a valid PDF with valid XML data... My issue is concerning lower facturx level such as Minimum, Basic, Basic WL.

The XML should look like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice 
    xmlns:qdt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:QualifiedDataType:100"
    xmlns:ram="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100"
    xmlns:rsm="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CrossIndustryInvoice:100"
    xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <rsm:ExchangedDocumentContext>
      <ram:BusinessProcessSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter>
         <ram:ID>A1</ram:ID>
      </ram:BusinessProcessSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter>
      <ram:GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter>
         <ram:ID>urn:factur-x.eu:1p0:minimum</ram:ID>
      </ram:GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter>
   </rsm:ExchangedDocumentContext>
   <rsm:ExchangedDocument>
      <ram:ID>NUMFCADNO22</ram:ID>
      <ram:TypeCode>380</ram:TypeCode>
      <ram:IssueDateTime>
         <udt:DateTimeString format="102">20220506</udt:DateTimeString>
      </ram:IssueDateTime>
   </rsm:ExchangedDocument>
   <rsm:SupplyChainTradeTransaction>
      <ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeAgreement>
         <ram:SellerTradeParty>
            <ram:Name>ACME</ram:Name>
            <ram:SpecifiedLegalOrganization>
               <ram:ID schemeID="0002">3810011234560073</ram:ID>
            </ram:SpecifiedLegalOrganization>
            <ram:PostalTradeAddress>
               <ram:CountryID>FR</ram:CountryID>
            </ram:PostalTradeAddress>
            <ram:SpecifiedTaxRegistration>
               <ram:ID schemeID="VA">FR17143232666</ram:ID>
            </ram:SpecifiedTaxRegistration>
         </ram:SellerTradeParty>
         <ram:BuyerTradeParty>
            <ram:Name>Client</ram:Name>
         </ram:BuyerTradeParty>
      </ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeAgreement>
      <ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeDelivery/>
      <ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeSettlement>
         <ram:InvoiceCurrencyCode>EUR</ram:InvoiceCurrencyCode>
         <ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummation>
            <ram:TaxBasisTotalAmount>200.00</ram:TaxBasisTotalAmount>
            <ram:TaxTotalAmount currencyID="EUR">40.00</ram:TaxTotalAmount>
            <ram:GrandTotalAmount>240.00</ram:GrandTotalAmount>
            <ram:DuePayableAmount>240.00</ram:DuePayableAmount>
         </ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummation>
      </ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeSettlement>
   </rsm:SupplyChainTradeTransaction>
</rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice>
```

My issue is that i have issues creating such attached document. Here, i do need to set :

- IssueDateTime
- Seller name( but constructor requires all information)
- Seller VAT ID
- Buyer name
- Currency
- Total

  - tax basis total amount
  - tax total amount
  - grand total amount
  - due payable amount

I partially found out how to set the profile.

```
ZUGFeRDExporterFromA1 ze = new ZUGFeRDExporterFromA1()
      .setProducer("My Application")
      .setCreator(System.getProperty("user.name"))
      .setZUGFeRDVersion(2)
      .setProfile("MINIMUM")
      .ignorePDFAErrors()
      .load("blanko.pdf");
```

I have issue concerning definig the invoice details:

```
    Invoice i = new Invoice()
            .setIssueDate(new Date())                                                                                   
            // .setDueDate(new Date()) ==> not required
            // .setDetailedDeliveryPeriod(new Date(), new Date()) ==> not required
            // .setDeliveryDate(new Date()) ==> not required
            .setSender(
                    new TradeParty("ACME", "", "", "", "FR")
                            .addVATID("FR17143232666"))
            .setRecipient(
                    new TradeParty("Client test MOA", "", "", "", "")
                            .addVATID("DE0815"))
            .setNumber("NUMFACTURE")
            .setCurrency("EUR")
            .setTotalPrepaidAmount(new BigDecimal("450.00"));
        ze.setTransaction(i);
        ze.export("factur-x-min.pdf");
```

I didn't find how to set values for required elements in Mustang and I have null pointers exceptions concerning dates for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trade Parties were defective, credit memos were defective and the minimum profile was most defective of all. Most of that should now be fixed in todays 2.6.0 and I also created a automatic test, which probably does most of what you want to do on https://github.com/ZUGFeRD/mustangproject/blob/master/library/src/test/java/org/mustangproject/ZUGFeRD/ProfilesMinimumBasicWLTest.java

You are so right that it really hurts you didn't just raise a Github issue, mention it in the mailing list https://groups.google.com/g/zugferd or via matrix (https://app.element.io/#/room/#facturx:matrix.org).

This is the second time that I actually learn of Chorus Pro requirements via Stackoverflow (besides, where do you have your sample from?) and I might have fixed this three months earlier if only I had been aware of it.

Joyeux Noël,
Jochen

PS: I believe in the context of the previous stackoverflow encounter I had investigated and BusinessProcessSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter=A1 may actually be optional in terms of Chorus Pro, i.e. B2G, and I would be astonished if that was any different in B2B.

Comment: Frohe Weihnachten ! well i didn't tried to open any Git issue. i was expecting that issue was on my fault and was just a configuration issue. 
I'm going to test now those new features and send to Chorus Pro. Actually, I just have to implement Min, BasicWL and later Basic fx. Ideally, a sample of each facturx in Mustang tests would be great. Luckily, at this time i was just working on a proof of concept and we just consider creating a real application right now. Thanks for the improvment.

Comment: PS: I will try to find out other issues and create a github issue for this.

Comment: Cool thanks, would be great to have a french reference user. And apologies for the lack of documentation, if I remember correctly even the issue "publish parts of the testcase for minimum+siret+chorus somewhere on the homepage" is still somewhere on my list.